# How do I create a Mixed Reality Speech Command Profile for another language?

Tags: hololens, mrtk

I am trying to create an application that can understand non english voice commands for Hololens2. I am trying to accomplish this without needing to go to the cloud as my use case cannot guarantee internet connectivity.

The documentation on Voice for Hololens 2 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/voice-input) states:

"HoloLens 2 also supports additional languages. Keep in mind that speech commands will always run in the system's display language even if multiple keyboards are installed or if apps attempt to create a speech recognizer in a different language."

This seems to mean that a user can use non english voice commands to control Hololens 2. However I cannot find any documentation or any way to create a Mixed Reality Speech Command Profile that will work when supplied with non english commands. Is this functionality supported?

I have tried creating a custom Mixed Reality Speech Command Profile and providing it with Spanish or Japanese commands. However native speakers are unable to trigger these commands despite my code flagging that it has in fact heard the user say something.

Comment: The MRTK's speech system is built on top of Unity's speech wrappers, which themselves wrap the windows speech recognition APIs. A quick search doesn't seem to show up anything on the "selecting the speech language" thing in Unity, but it looks like it's possible to change the underlying windows speech language using something like this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/specify-the-speech-recognizer-language

FWIW It might also be worth filing an issue on the MRTK to better support this - I think that this is something we should have thought out in the MRTK better

Comment: Before answering your question, I'd like to confirm with you what hardware we are looking at. May I ask the current HoloLens device version you are working on? Gen 1 or 2? What language is your HoloLens device's system?

Comment: Will, thank you for this information it gives me a direction to start digging in.

Franklin, at the moment I am working with HoloLens1, with the latest OS. However given that MRTK has supported building for Hololens2 for a while now, I am developing a solution that is designed to run on Hololens2 and testing using the emulator so that when we get our devices we don't have to start from scratch. My Hololens 1 device is currently in english and as far as my research shows it is incapable of supporting the feature I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For question that if there is a way to create a Mixed Reality speech command profile that will work when supplied with **non English commands** when running on **English version** HoloLens device.

The short answer is no. The language model for speech is based on the selected UI language and its dictionary is built on real words for that language, so the recognizer will not recognize foreign words without **first switching the UI language to the appropriate native language**. The premise is the HoloLens supports that native language.

The truth is only three languages is supported for HoloLens 1st Gen - English, Simplified Chinese and Japanese. The good news is the HoloLens 2nd Gen does have support for more languages than the original device. Please check out our official HoloLens 2 documentation: [Supported languages for HoloLens 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens2-language-support)